# Multidimensional array combines same key and value into already defined array element

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I new to php, getting mysql results storing json but its not gettng coorect format what I want.

Pease check below code

```
$sql = "select * from en_providers where providerEmailAddress='" . $email . "' and providerPW='" . $password . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $resultArray = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $providerID               = $row['providerID'];
        $resultArray['providers'] = $row;
        $resultArray['providers']['providerIDActivities'] = unserialize($row['providerIDActivities']);
        $resultArray['providers']['providerIDBodies'] = unserialize($row['providerIDBodies']);
        $resultArray['providers']['providerIDOthers'] = unserialize($row['providerIDOthers']);

        $sql1 = "select * from en_venues where providerID = $providerID ";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));
        $i = $j = $l = $x = $m = 0;
        while ($row1[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
            //$resultArray['venues'][]['venueIDFacilities'] = unserialize($row1[$j++]['venueIDFacilities']);
            $venueID                                          = $row1[$j++]['venueID'];
            $k                                                = 0;
            $venueFacilities                                  = unserialize($row1[$i++]['venueIDFacilities']);
            $resultArray[$x++]['venues']['venueIDFacilities'] = $venueFacilities;

            //$resultArray['venues'][$x++]['venueID'] = $venueID;
            $resultArray['venues'] = $row1;
            //echo json_encode($resultArray);



        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
{
    0: {
        "venues": {
            "venueIDFacilities": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
            ],
        }
    },
    1: {
        "venues": {
            "venueIDFacilities": [
                "4",
                "7"
            ],
        }
    }
},
"providers": {
    "providerIDActivities": [
        "218",
        "219"
    ],
    "providerIDSports": "a:1:{i:0;i:82;}",
    "providerIDBodies": [
        "112"
    ],
},
venues": {
    0: {
        "venueID": "9",
        "providerID": "2"
    },
    1: {
        "venueID": "238",
        "providerID": "2",
        "venueActive": "yes"
    }
}
```

But I need those `VenueFailities` to be in respective venues but result is getting outside. How can I append those values into venues?

I am trying for one day with different ways but it's not getting correct format.

Output I want:

```
"providers": {
    "providerIDActivities": [
        "218",
        "219"
    ],
    "providerIDSports": "a:1:{i:0;i:82;}",
    "providerIDBodies": [
        "112"
    ],
},
venues": {
    0: {
        "venueID": "9",
        "providerID": "2",
        "venueIDFacilities": [
            "4",
            "7"
        ]
    },
    1: {
        "venueID": "238",
        "providerID": "2",
        venueIDFacilities": [
            "4",
            "7"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: that's a lot of code for a simple question, please reduce your code

Comment: This code has other issues: don't perform SQL statements inside another loop that iterates a result set. Instead improve your initial SQL using joins. More importantly, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You really should use prepared statements and bind arguments.

Comment: Ok @trincot I will chagne its urgent can you solve above issue

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
$resultArray[$x++]['venues']['venueIDFacilities'] = $venueFacilities;
```

should be

```
$resultArray['venues'][$x++]['venueIDFacilities'] = $venueFacilities;
```

Comment: for that I am getting only first value but not in venues array please open link https://codeshare.io/5zXL97